# Is there any way to fetch spec of a Kubernetes Resource using metadata like resource name, kind, namespace?

Tags: java, kubernetes

I investigated io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis, seems like they only have methods returning specific object for specific kind (eg. V1Deployment,V1ConfigMap for kind Deployment,ConfigMap respectively)

Using switch case for all Kind doesn't seem a feasible solution to me, Isn't there any way we can fetch Resource spec as String irrespective of its Kind through Kubernetes Java Client?

Comment: I'm curious to know if there's a way as well but I don't think that's the case, as Kubernetes API are organized in that way. It's not a thing of the Java Client, the Rest API works that way. They make distinctions for resource-type, namespaces and so on. It makes sense, as they could need to check if the caller is authorized to see a certain resource or use a certain REST method. ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/ )